# Mapping database where every relation is a table

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I got my database, which is created with litesql(C++ ORM framework), and there every relation is implemented as a single table(like many-to-many). How my JPA mapping should look like?

Example

```
CREATE TABLE Car (
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR
)
CREATE TABLE Engine (
    id INTEGER,
    model INTEGER
)
CREATE TABLE CarEngine (
    car INTEGER,
    engine INTEGER
)
```

There are no foreign keys but there are UNIQUE constraints on relationship table depending on relationship type(many to many - no constraints, one to many - one constraint, one to one  - two constraints)

Comment: Have you tried something? What's the problem?

Comment: Oh, I forgot. I dont want relationships to be entities and i would like not to have them all mapped as many to many.

Comment: Unidirectional OneToMany are mapped by a join table by default, and although uncommon, I don't think you can't map a OneToOne using a JoinTable. Just do it, with the same JoinTable annotation as the one you'd use for a ManyToMany.

Comment: Post is it as an answer, because you solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unidirectional `OneToMany` are mapped by a join table by default, and although uncommon, I don't think you can't map a `OneToOne` using a JoinTable. Just do it, with the same `JoinTable` annotation as the one you'd use for a `ManyToMany`.